# preg_replace dont replace values

Tags: php

I wrote a function to strip parameters from urls, the function looks like this

```
function remove_it($c_link){

        $regex = array();
        $award = array();

        $regex[] = '/[\?&](?<name>sa)=(?<value>[^&=]+)/';
        $regex[] = '/[\?&](?<name>ei)=(?<value>[^&=]+)/';
        $regex[] = '/[\?&](?<name>ved)=(?<value>[^&=]+)/';
        $regex[] = '/[\?&](?<name>usg)=(?<value>[^&=]+)/';

        foreach($regex as $remove){

            $c_link = preg_replace($remove,'',$c_link);

        }

        return $c_link;

    }
```

When I use a testurl like this

```
$test = 'http://forum.gofeminin.de/forum/dietetique/__f2955_dietetique-Diatpillen.html&sa=U&ei=8doOUa6HOsfKtAaDpICIBQ&ved=0CB0QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEcFS48QvteNkSNcszXv5RG6VUe2g';
```

It's woking perfect. Now I wanted to use it in my code. So I called to function with my data and it doesn't affect the string. I used print_r to see if the string looks strange, but it's just 1:1 like in $test

```
$TEST-> http://forum.gofeminin.de/forum/dietetique/__f2955_dietetique-Diatpillen.html&sa=U&ei=C9wOUZuvCoeQtQavpoHoDg&ved=0CB0QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHkRBKRpZXZX7idJ6YmSG0AIxtOdw
print_r-> http://forum.gofeminin.de/forum/dietetique/__f2955_dietetique-Diatpillen.html&sa=U&ei=C9wOUZuvCoeQtQavpoHoDg&ved=0CB0QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHkRBKRpZXZX7idJ6YmSG0AIxtOdw
```

As I used all debugging methods that I know of, I don't really know where I should start searching... any pointers ?

I made antoher testrun, and saved all data in an array, later on I wanted to stript the parameter for 1 url. Here the testcode:

```
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($test).'</br>';
    echo remove_it($test[0]);
    echo '</pre>';
    break;
```

the output was like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://forum.gofeminin.de/forum/dietetique/__f2955_dietetique-Diatpillen.html&sa=U&ei=LOIOUaqQGITntQbmmIHYBQ&ved=0CDUQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGgMS-nHM2JY_PkIt7C_RT2dr9bUw
    [1] => http://www.fitforfun.de/abnehmen/gesund-essen/diaetpillen/diaetpillen-appetitzuegler_aid_2100.html&sa=U&ei=LOIOUaqQGITntQbmmIHYBQ&ved=0CEEQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNG60KJy3wLR8DnLm9gKQEn-uR6l3w
    [2] => http://www.stern.de/ernaehrung/uebergewicht-abnehmen/diaetpillen-check-welche-mittel-machen-duenn-das-abc-der-schlankmacher-615772.html&sa=U&ei=LOIOUaqQGITntQbmmIHYBQ&ved=0CEYQFjAC&usg=AFQjCNGLzi5UMG4g5INDkeBdMpENgY4gHg
    [3] => http://getslim.de/diaetpillen-im-test&sa=U&ei=LOIOUaqQGITntQbmmIHYBQ&ved=0CEoQFjAD&usg=AFQjCNEcZnpSlVVxLgskK9DfhBF9AHGC2w
    [4] => http://www.br.de/fernsehen/bayerisches-fernsehen/sendungen/gesundheit/themenuebersicht/medizin/schlankheitspillen-diaet-tabletten100.html&sa=U&ei=LOIOUaqQGITntQbmmIHYBQ&ved=0CFQQFjAE&usg=AFQjCNHujKjdfNsOkarYf6MwHCPODcISjw
    [5] => http://www.diaetpillenvergleich.de/beste-diatpillen/&sa=U&ei=LOIOUaqQGITntQbmmIHYBQ&ved=0CFoQFjAF&usg=AFQjCNFBgbYjgutHJfp-eQztXTsKYk7rTw
    [6] => http://www.diaetpillen-online.de/&sa=U&ei=LOIOUaqQGITntQbmmIHYBQ&ved=0CF4QFjAG&usg=AFQjCNF083onO0rkMuQjY0tEIhhdSM4Igg
    [7] => http://diaet.erdbeerlounge.de/Diaetpillen/&sa=U&ei=LOIOUaqQGITntQbmmIHYBQ&ved=0CGIQFjAH&usg=AFQjCNFhNr-gsFxK1-vfjhnC1A5qQi1ZjQ
    [8] => http://diaet.erdbeerlounge.de/abnehmen-forum/Diaetpillen-_t2698848s1&sa=U&ei=LOIOUaqQGITntQbmmIHYBQ&ved=0CGcQFjAI&usg=AFQjCNHhHY3zUnJtwF6-HV-DbsxaVUFxsg
    [9] => http://www.gutefrage.net/tag/diaetpillen/1&sa=U&ei=LOIOUaqQGITntQbmmIHYBQ&ved=0CG0QFjAJ&usg=AFQjCNHPYODXZA1Sa2rs6ItnUWTOYkJj3w
)
http://forum.gofeminin.de/forum/dietetique/__f2955_dietetique-Diatpillen.html&sa=U&ei=LOIOUaqQGITntQbmmIHYBQ&ved=0CDUQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGgMS-nHM2JY_PkIt7C_RT2dr9bUw
```

Comment: Works for me. Could you post test code that doesn't?

Comment: its an url string from a curl parse, i.e. the print_r data was from there, but as you can see it's 1 : 1 the same url. So im getting crazy why it doesnt work. When I test it with $test it's also working with me, when I copy the urls in test and run them, they also get stripped. but when I call the function directly it doesnt work with the given data from curl. It's a normal formed string with the url in it... im getting crazy :D

Comment: Still works for me. http://pastebin.com/jgX8k96i

Comment: with premade data its also working for me,.. but not with parsed data ..

Comment: Maybe the parsing isn't returning the string properly. Maybe it's encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the test array and it works for me. It seems that your code is fine and something else is wrong.

Try wrapping the function input in double quotes.

```
remove_it("$test[0]");
```

Comment: How do you "call the function directly" with "with the given data from curl"?

Comment: I parse the links out of the html, and echo them wrapped in the function

Comment: Show the line where you put the data into $test array.